# Memory allocation by threads in c

Tags: c, linux

How could I reduce memory used by threads in C? Although a thread takes about 8 to 10 MB of memory, is there any way to reduce this memory?

Comment: If you think about this rationally, it shouldn't become a problem. How many cores does your CPU have? How many threads are you trying to start? If you're trying to start 2000 threads, memory won't be the only problem you face.

Comment: Another thing to consider is that on most systems the stack is allocated in chunks of pages (typically around 4Kb) one at a time anyways and grows automatically. Even if your threads library allocates X amount of MB for the stack it doesn't mean that they are actually physically being used. As an experiment: write a program that allocates all your available physical RAM and then sleeps. Run it and check it's actual used memory (RSS, Resident Set).

Answer (score 6):

yes you can set the size of thread stack.

```
pthread_attr_t attribute;
pthread_t thread;
pthread_attr_init(&attribute);
pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attribute,size); // size may be defined by u as 1024,2048,etc
pthread_create(&thread,&attribute,fun,0);
```

................................................

```
void *fun(void *arg)
{
      ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As already replied you can use the pthread attribute in your application.

But you can also set a limit to any application launched in the current shell with the ulimit command:

- `ulimit -s` : show the current limit in kiB
- `ulimit -s 1024` : limit the stack to 1 MiB